# How to update google docs api namedrange text in c#?

Tags: c#, json, api, text, documentation

I want to insert text from c# textbox1 to google docs template body namedrange "BoddyTitle"  and from textbox2 to body namedrange "BoddyContent" .

Because indexes of created namedrange is modifying for every update, I need to get value of that indexes before update with new text.

Pls help get that indexes.

```
List <Request> requests = new List<Request>
{
};

requests.Add(new Request() 
{  
   ReplaceNamedRangeContent = new ReplaceNamedRangeContentRequest()  
  { 
       Text = textBox1.Text,  NamedRangeName = "BoddyTitle" 
  } 
}); // Index = 5-50, 
                              
requests.Add(new Request()  
{  
  ReplaceNamedRangeContent = new ReplaceNamedRangeContentRequest() 
  {  
     Text = textBox2.Text,  NamedRangeName = "BoddyContent" 
  } 
}); // Index = 55-10000,

BatchUpdateDocumentRequest body = new BatchUpdateDocumentRequest { Requests = requests };

dservice.Documents.BatchUpdate(body, docid).Execute();
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "because indexes of created namedrange is modifiyng for every update". What indexes do you mean? Your code has comments referencing indexes, but no actual code that references indexes.

Comment: What is happening that shouldn't happen, or not happening that should? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: i want to read startindex and endindex of namedrange location  via c# code , google docs api have exemple in java or python but i need c#

Comment: here exemple  https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/named-ranges

Answer (score 0):

resolved, here the code

```
 List<Request> requests = new List<Request> { };

        DocumentsResource.GetRequest req = dservice.Documents.Get(docid);
        Document doc = req.Execute();


        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < doc.Body.Content.Count; i++)
        {
            if (doc.Body.Content[i].EndIndex.Value > max)
            {
                max = doc.Body.Content[i].EndIndex.Value;
            }
        }

        if (max < 3)
        {
         //   requests.Add(new Request() { DeleteNamedRange = new DeleteNamedRangeRequest() { Name = "BoddyTitle" } });
         //   requests.Add(new Request() { DeleteNamedRange = new DeleteNamedRangeRequest() { Name = "BoddyContent", } });
            requests.Add(new Request() { InsertText = new InsertTextRequest() { Text = "\n\nx", Location = new Location { Index = 1 } } });
            requests.Add(new Request() { InsertText = new InsertTextRequest() { Text = "\n\nx", Location = new Location() { SegmentId = "", Index = 4 } } });
            requests.Add(new Request() { CreateNamedRange = new CreateNamedRangeRequest() { Name = "BoddyTitle", Range = new Range() { SegmentId = "", StartIndex = 3, EndIndex = 4 } } });
            requests.Add(new Request() { CreateNamedRange = new CreateNamedRangeRequest() { Name = "BoddyContent", Range = new Range() { SegmentId = "", StartIndex = 6, EndIndex = 7 } } });
        }

                  
        //                   requests.Add(new Request() { DeleteContentRange = new DeleteContentRangeRequest() { Range = new Range { StartIndex = 1, EndIndex = max - 1 } } });


        if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "")
        {
          requests.Add(new Request() { ReplaceNamedRangeContent = new ReplaceNamedRangeContentRequest() { Text = textBox1.Text.Replace("\r\n", "\n"), NamedRangeName = "BoddyTitle" } });
          requests.Add(new Request() { ReplaceNamedRangeContent = new ReplaceNamedRangeContentRequest() { Text = textBox2.Text.Replace("\r\n", "\n"), NamedRangeName = "BoddyContent" } });
           
        }
          else { MessageBox.Show("Textbox Empty" ); }

        if (requests.Count >0)
        {
            BatchUpdateDocumentRequest body = new BatchUpdateDocumentRequest { Requests = requests };
            dservice.Documents.BatchUpdate(body, docid).Execute();Process.Start("https://docs.google.com/document/d/doc_id/edit?usp=sharing");
        }
```